# Como funciona el operador || en este caso?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Este codigo al parecer verifica si una variable es true, y si no, crea la variable:

```
(function(a){
a || (a = "Default value");
})();
```

Por que solo funciona cuando se hace con parentesis el defecto ? , me refiero a :

```
(a = "Default value")
```

Ademas, como se llama esto ? y que realiza efectivamente ?

Comment: las variables booleanas en javascript se tratan de una forma peculiar, te dejo el siguiente enalce donde lo explican mas a detalle: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Boolean#Ejemplos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El operador `||` es la función lógica conocida como **OR**.

Esta función recibe 2 parámetros, y su funcionamiento puede describirse como; devolver `false` si *ambos* parámetros son `false`. Sino, devolver `true`. Por lo tanto en JavaScript:

```
false || false   ==> false
false || true    ==> true
true  || true    ==> true
true  || false   ==> true
```

Si observas con atención, la implementación del operador `||`, puede simplificarse un poco: devolver `true` si el primer parámetro es `true`. Sino, devolver el segundo parámetro. Y esto es realmente lo que hace JavaScript. Demostrando:

```
true  || 3   ==> true
false || 3   ==> 3
```

Ahora, no sé si escuchaste sobre los valores ***falsy*** de JavaScript. Estos valores *falsy*, son todos aquellos valores que JavaScript considera como si fueran `false`. Y puedes probar estos valores usando el operador `||`. Por ejemplo:

```
   null   || 5   ==> 5
undefined || 5   ==> 5
    0     || 5   ==> 5
   NaN    || 5   ==> 5
    ''    || 5   ==> 5
    ""    || 5   ==> 5
```

---

Ahora.. **¿Qué ocurre con tu expresión?**

```
a || (a = "Algún valor")
```

La variable `a`, se encuentra declarada previamente (En la definición: `function(a)`). Por lo tanto, no se considera como un error.
Sin embargo, `a` no contiene valor previo, o mas bien, contiene el valor por defecto: `undefined`.

Ahora resumiendo todo, cuando ejecutas:

```
a || (a = "Algún valor")
```

Si `a` se declaró pero no tiene valor, se interpreta como:

```
undefined || (acción) ==> Ejecuta la acción, que asigna un valor a la variable a.
```

Si `a` tiene un valor previo, que no sea uno *falsy*, se interpreta como:

```
true || (accion) ==> Como el primer parámetro es true, no ejecuta la acción.
```

Recordar que la operación `||` al final devuelve `true` o `false`. Pero el resultado se descarta ya que no estás usando el mismo de ninguna forma.

---

En cuanto a tu otra duda: **¿Por qué solo funciona con paréntesis?**

```
a || (a = 2) // Funciona
a ||  a = 2  // No funciona
```

Esto ya tiene que ver con cómo puede interpretar JavaScript ese código.
En el segundo caso, no funciona porque no se puede saber cual es el segundo parámetro para el operador `||`. El segundo parámetro puede ser `a`. Pero también puede ser `a = 2` que es lo que querías. 
Mientras en el primer caso está claramente definido entre paréntesis cual es el segundo parámetro.

---

Por último:

```
(function(a){
a || (a = "Default value");
})();
```

Eso solamente es un bloque de código grande. Una parte del mismo, es el cuerpo de la función, que ya vimos es la función *OR*. Ahora puedes ver esa cochinada como:

```
(function(){
  // ... Cuerpo de la función anónima
})();
```

Si limpias un poquito más:

```
let funcion = function(){..};
(funcion)();
```

Queda más claro a la vista que es la declaración de una función anónima. Y apenas se termina de declarar, se ejecuta llamando a los paréntesis `()`.

Curiosamente, esto tiene un nombre: *Immediately Invoked Function Expression* (Función invocada inmediatamente) abreviado comúnmente como **IIFE**.

Que es en resumen lo que se explicó. Una función que se invoca inmediatamente tras su declaración.

Answer (score 1):

Resumiendo un poco, el operador && y || son operadores conocidos como corto-circuito, se llaman asi porque evaluan el lado derecho **solo si  es necesario**

por ejemplo

```
var x=true;
x==true|| true
```

`x==true` es verdadero por lo tanto ya  cumple con la `condicion`  no es necesario evaluar el lado derecho.

**ahora un ejemplo con &&**

```
var x=true;
var y=false;
var z=false;
x==false && y==false  && z==true
```

falla en `x==false` asi que no se evalua el lado derecho(`&& y==false  && z==true`) porque ya hubo un fallo.

**ahora analizando tu caso:**

```
(function(a){
a || a = "Default value";
})();
```

no funciona por que el lenguaje no puede interpretar cual es el valor, si es `a` o el operador `=` , etc.

Comment: ? , creo que no has comprendido, con los parentesis, si funciona

Comment: @EduardoSebastian listo borre los parentesis